# How can I drop duplicates in my DataFrame without the error "KeyError: Index(['CVE ID'], dtype='object')"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use the `drop_duplicate` function to remove duplicate rows based off my `CVE ID` column in my DataFrame.

**Main.py**

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
csv_filename = 'registry_9_23_22_11_25_20'

with open(f"{csv_filename}.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)  

df_source = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=[data[0]])
df = df_source[['CVE ID','Description', 'Vulnerability ID', 'Id', 'Fix Status', 'Severity']]

column_headers = list(df.columns.values)
print(column_headers)

unique_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CVE ID'])

print(unique_df)
```

Here are my column names when I print them:

```
[('CVE ID',), ('Description',), ('Vulnerability ID',), ('Id',), ('Fix Status',), ('Severity',)]
```

Now when I try to use the drop_duplicate function and set the subset to 'CVE ID', it gives me this error:

```
KeyError: Index(['CVE ID'], dtype='object')
```

Based on their docs I just have to supply the column name to drop all of the rows that contain duplicate values from the 'CVE ID' column. Am I doing it wrong somehow?

Comment: Your column names when you print them are inside tuples, that looks suspicious

Comment: Are your columns a MultiIndex?

Comment: @G.Anderson I have no clue what that is, I'm a newby with Dataframes, did I create my columns incorrectly?

Comment: @Daraan Why are they tuples? I'm pretty new with Pandas and just want normal columns lol

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure either. Normally you just use `print(df.columns)` it should yield the same result, does it?  You could try `df.drop_duplicates(subset=[('CVE ID',)])` for verification.

Comment: You can load the csv directly with pandas pd.read_csv(filename). See here for more details [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)